# How to Add an Object to a Json Array Depending a value of another Key in the File Using JoltTransformationJson in NiFi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

This is my first time to use **JoltTransformationJson**, so I have limited knowledge and experience on that. Please help me with this complicated project.

Request:
when the ***payment.code <> "paid"***, I have to do the following two things for the file.

1. to change the ***payment.code ="denied"*** and ***payment.text ="denied"***
2. to add a *JSON* object to **item.ADJ**

When the ***payment.code =="paid"***, don't need to change anything.

**Input** :

```json
{
  "resourceType": "E",
  "id": "11",
  "identifier": [
    {
      "type": {
        "coding": [
          {
            "system": "sys1",
            "code": "aaa"
          }
        ]
      },
      "value": "212"
    },
    {
      "type": {
        "coding": [
          {
            "system": "sys2",
            "code": "RRR"
          }
        ]
      },
      "value": "367"
    }
  ],
  "status": "active",
  "created": "2021-08-05T02:43:48+00:00",
  "outcome": "complete",
  "item": [
    {
      "sequence": 1,
      "product": {
        "coding": [
          {
            "system": "example",
            "code": "abc",
            "display": "ABC"
          }
        ],
        "text": "ABC"
      },
      "servicedDate": "2021-08-04",
      "quantity": {
        "value": 60
      },
      "ADJ": [
        {
          "category": {
            "coding": [
              {
                "system": "code1",
                "code": "code1",
                "display": "CODE1"
              }
            ],
            "text": "CODE1"
          },
          "amount": {
            "value": 46.45,
            "currency": "USD"
          }
        },
        {
          "category": {
            "coding": [
              {
                "system": "code2",
                "code": "code2",
                "display": "CODE2"
              }
            ],
            "text": "CODE2"
          },
          "amount": {
            "value": 12.04,
            "currency": "USD"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "payment": {
    "type": {
      "coding": [
        {
          "system": "http://payment.com",
          "code": "reversed/cancelled"
        }
      ],
      "text": "cancelled"
    }
  }
}
```

**My Expected Output** :

```json
{
  "resourceType": "E",
  "id": "11",
  "identifier": [
    {
      "type": {
        "coding": [
          {
            "system": "sys1",
            "code": "aaa"
          }
        ]
      },
      "value": "212"
    },
    {
      "type": {
        "coding": [
          {
            "system": "sys2",
            "code": "RRR"
          }
        ]
      },
      "value": "367"
    }
  ],
  "status": "active",
  "created": "2021-08-05T02:43:48+00:00",
  "outcome": "complete",
  "item": [
    {
      "sequence": 1,
      "product": {
        "coding": [
          {
            "system": "example",
            "code": "abc",
            "display": "ABC"
          }
        ],
        "text": "ABC"
      },
      "servicedDate": "2021-08-04",
      "quantity": {
        "value": 60
      },
      "ADJ": [
        {
          "category": {
            "coding": [
              {
                "system": "code1",
                "code": "code1",
                "display": "CODE1"
              }
            ],
            "text": "CODE1"
          },
          "amount": {
            "value": 46.45,
            "currency": "USD"
          }
        },
        {
          "category": {
            "coding": [
              {
                "system": "code2",
                "code": "code2",
                "display": "CODE2"
              }
            ],
            "text": "CODE2"
          },
          "amount": {
            "value": 12.04,
            "currency": "USD"
          }
        },
        {// new object I want to insert into
          "category": {
            "coding": [
              {
                "system": "sys_denail",
                "code": "denialreason"
              }
            ],
          "reason": {
            "coding": [
              {
                "system": "https://example.com",
                "code": "A1"
              }
            ],
            "text": "unknown"
          }}
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "payment": {
    "type": {
      "coding": [
        {
          "system": "http://payment.com",
          "code": "denied" //change the value to denied
        }
      ],
      "text": "denied" //change the value to denied
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit :** *I've tried to answer the second case by myself to be evaluated after the first case is answered*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO, please [ask minimal and reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and show your effort tried for the future.

What you need is to use a conditional logic along with placeholder values with ampersand symbols depending on the levels of each key name within the tree.

I have partially answered, which will handle the bottom part of your question. Indeed the logic for the rest(*inserting an object to the array will be similiar*)

So, consider having a look at the following solution

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "payment": {
        "type": {
          "coding": {
            "*": {
              "*": "&4.&3.&2[&1].&",
              "code": {
                "paid": {
                  "@1": "&6.&5.&4[&3].&2",
                  "@(4,text)": "&6.text"
                },
                "*": {
                  "#denied": "&6.&5.&4[&3].code",
                  "@(4,text)": {
                    "#denied": "&6.text"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Edit**(*for your own answer related to adding an object*)**:**

your current idea of using **shift** after **default** transformation spec is pretty good, you can rephrase like

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "temp_deny": {
        "denialreason": {
          "category": {
            "coding": [
              {
                "system": "sys_denail",
                "code": "denialreason"
              }
            ],
            "reason": {
              "coding": [
                {
                  "system": "https://example.com",
                  "code": "A1"
              }
            ],
              "text": "unknown"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "item": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2[&1].&",
          "ADJ": {
            "@": "&3[&2].&",
            "@(4,temp_deny)": "&3[&2].&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi Barbaros, thank you so much for your help. It is working very well. Here is my current work as follows for adding the "denial reason" object(contain array) to the file, but it failed. And, I also cannot put them into the condition when the payment.code is not "paid". Please help me with it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @DataLady , After answering your last work I've added an extra explanation to the question if you don't mind..

Comment: Thanks, Barbaros. The code worked except for the another copy of "temp_deny" in the first level of data. Thank you so much for your support.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Yes, I would like to upvote, but could you tell me how? I am sorry that I am so new for SO.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me. I did it.